# How to add a parameter to the url with typoscript in TMENU

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

with the following snippet I get an ID counting up for every following menu item, this is the html output:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/index.php?id=17" id="item-1"> <!-- item-2 etc -->
```

but I'd need this counting up with the following output:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php?id=17&item=1"> <!-- item=2 etc -->
```

**the snippet:**

```
1 = TMENU
1 {
    expAll = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
        before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
        before.cObject{
            fontawesome.cObject=TEXT
            fontawesome.cObject.required = 1
            fontawesome.cObject.data.dataWrap = DB:pages:{field:uid}:tt_content_fontawesome_icon
            fontawesome.cObject.noTrimWrap = | <i class="fa |"></i> |
        }
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        linkWrap = {register:fontawesome}|
        ATagParams = id="item-{register:count_MENUOBJ}"
        allStdWrap.insertData = 1
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    }
}
```

I tried with **`typolink {}`** and **`additionalParams`** but that makes **`{register:count_MENUOBJ}`** unavailable for a reason I cannot grasp, probabely some conflict within data types ...

also the **`linkwrap`** with **`{register:fontawesome}`** is delicate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of NO {} try these two lines without allStdWrap.insertData:

```
additionalParams.data = register:count_MENUOBJ
additionalParams.wrap = &item=|
```

If it would not work, try another value to check if it basically would work:

```
additionalParams.data = field:uid
additionalParams.wrap = &item=|
```

Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html

Comment: they both work just fine !! I did read up on the reference linked but didn't get this extra step you introduced ... where could I find good information on basic typoscript ?

Comment: The link provided has full information of Typoscript. You should start with the `Setup` or `Content Objects (cObjects)` in the menu. Content Objects are basically all "objects" like a menu or content in the TS.